# Unable to replace a particular value from an array column in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a column in my DF where data type is :

```
testcolumn:array  
--element: struct
-----id:integer   
-----configName: string 
-----desc:string  
-----configparam:array
--------element:map  
-------------key:string
-------------value:string
```

testcolumn
**Row1:**

```
[{"id":1,"configName":"test1","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":2,"configName":"test2","desc":"Ram2","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":3,"configName":"test3","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]}]
```

**Row2:**

```
[{"id":11,"configName":"test11","desc":"Ram11","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":33,"configName":"test33","desc":"Ram33","configparam":[{"paramId":"43","paramvalue":"300"}]},
{"id":6,"configName":"test26","desc":"Ram26","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":93,"configName":"test93","desc":"Ram93","configparam":[{"paramId":"93","paramvalue":"3009"}]}
]
```

I want to remove where configparam is **"configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]**  to **"configparam":[]**

**expecting output:**
outputcolumn

**Row1:**

```
[{"id":1,"configName":"test1","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[]},
{"id":2,"configName":"test2","desc":"Ram2","configparam":[]},
{"id":3,"configName":"test3","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]}]
```

**Row2:**

```
[{"id":11,"configName":"test11","desc":"Ram11","configparam":[]},
{"id":33,"configName":"test33","desc":"Ram33","configparam":[{"paramId":"43","paramvalue":"300"}]},
{"id":6,"configName":"test26","desc":"Ram26","configparam":[]},
{"id":93,"configName":"test93","desc":"Ram93","configparam":[{"paramId":"93","paramvalue":"3009"}]}
]
```

I have tried this code but it is not giving me output:

```py
test=df.withColumn('outputcolumn',F.expr("translate"(testcolumn,x-> replace(x,':[{"removeit":"[]"}]','[]')))
```

it will be really great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `testcolumn` is an array of struct so you cannot do a string operation as it is.

You can do something like this. This will empty `configparam` completely when it *contains* a key "removeit".

Example:

```
"configparam":[{"removeit":[], "otherparam": "value"}] -> "configparam": []
```

#### Spark 3.1.0+

```py
array_has_remove = lambda y: ~F.array_contains(F.map_keys(y), 'removeit')

df = (df.withColumn('outputcolumn', 
          F.transform('testcolumn', 
              lambda x: x.withField('configparam', 
                  F.filter(x['configparam'], array_has_remove)
              )
          )
     ))
```

Ref:
[withField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html), [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html), [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html), [map_keys](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys.html)

#### <Spark3.1.0

I tried without `explode` but this is complex. If you don't like this complex, you can try using `explode` and aggregate.

```py
df = (# extract configparam to a column for easier access.
      df.withColumn('configparam', F.expr('transform(testcolumn, x -> x.configparam)'))
        # Return empty array if there is a "removeit" otherwise return the original object.
        .withColumn('configparam', 
            F.expr('transform(configparam, x -> 
                        case when array_contains(map_keys(x[0]), "removeit") then array() 
                        else x end)'))
        # Patch the transformed configparam with the rest of testcolumn
        .withColumn('outputcolumn', 
            F.expr('transform(testcolumn, (x, i) -> struct(x.id, x.configName, x.desc, configparam[i] as configparam))'))
        .drop('configparam'))
```

Result

```
Row(testcolumn=[Row(id=1, configName='test1', desc='Ram1', configparam=[{'removeit': '[]'}]), Row(id=2, configName='test2', desc='Ram2', configparam=[{'removeit': '[]'}]), Row(id=3, configName='test3', desc='Ram1', configparam=[{'paramId': '4', 'paramvalue': '200'}])], 
  outputcolumn=[Row(id=1, configName='test1', desc='Ram1', configparam=[]), Row(id=2, configName='test2', desc='Ram2', configparam=[]), Row(id=3, configName='test3', desc='Ram1', configparam=[{'paramId': '4', 'paramvalue': '200'}])])
```

Comment: getting error : module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: What version of Spark you are using?

Comment: 2.4.5, using databricks

Comment: I put the solution for the one that should work for 2.4.5. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform a chain of explode, filter and groupBy operations to achieve this.

First, explode array/struct/map columns to reach to the nested column:

```py
df = df.withColumn("id", F.col("testcolumn")["id"])
df = df.withColumn("configName", F.col("testcolumn")["configName"])
df = df.withColumn("desc", F.col("testcolumn")["desc"])
df = df.withColumn("configparam_exploded", F.explode(F.col("testcolumn")["configparam"]))
df = df.select(df.columns + [F.explode(F.col("configparam_exploded"))])

+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
|testcolumn                                           |id |configName|desc|configparam_exploded             |key       |value|
+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
|{1, test1, Ram1, [{removeit -> []}]}                 |1  |test1     |Ram1|{removeit -> []}                 |removeit  |[]   |
|{2, test2, Ram2, [{removeit -> []}]}                 |2  |test2     |Ram2|{removeit -> []}                 |removeit  |[]   |
|{3, test3, Ram1, [{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}]}|3  |test3     |Ram1|{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}|paramId   |4    |
|{3, test3, Ram1, [{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}]}|3  |test3     |Ram1|{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}|paramvalue|200  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
```

Then, filter data as required:

```py
df = df.filter((F.col("key") != "removeit") | (F.col("value") != "[]"))

+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
|testcolumn                                           |id |configName|desc|configparam_exploded             |key       |value|
+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
|{3, test3, Ram1, [{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}]}|3  |test3     |Ram1|{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}|paramId   |4    |
|{3, test3, Ram1, [{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}]}|3  |test3     |Ram1|{paramId -> 4, paramvalue -> 200}|paramvalue|200  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----------+----+---------------------------------+----------+-----+
```

Finally, groupBy all individual columns back to original packing:

```py
df = df.withColumn("configparam_map", F.map_from_entries(F.array(F.struct("key", "value"))))
df = df.groupBy(["id", "configName", "desc"]).agg(F.collect_list("configparam_map").alias("configparam"))
df = df.withColumn("testcolumn", F.struct("id", "configName", "desc", "configparam"))
df = df.drop("id", "configName", "desc", "configparam")

+-------------------------------------------------------+
|testcolumn                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|{3, test3, Ram1, [{paramId -> 4}, {paramvalue -> 200}]}|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sample dataset used to reproduce the problem:

```py
schema = StructType([StructField('testcolumn', StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(), True), StructField('configName', StringType(), True), StructField('desc', StringType(), True), StructField('configparam', ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True), True)]), True)])

data = [
  Row(Row(1, "test1", "Ram1", [{"removeit":"[]"}])),
  Row(Row(2, "test2", "Ram2", [{"removeit":"[]"}])),
  Row(Row(3, "test3", "Ram1", [{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]))    
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
```

Comment: output require with column name also ,like json format, please see once my expected output

Comment: Column names are in schema, and header of dataframe. It is never part of data. What is the output of your `df.limit(3).show(truncate=False)`?

Comment: it should not be only value ,it should contain key also.like:
[{"id":1,"configName":"test1","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[]},
{"id":2,"configName":"test2","desc":"Ram2","configparam":[]},
{"id":3,"configName":"test3","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]}]

Comment: Your schema does not match with your data. What is output of `print(df.schema)`?

Comment: input:
[{"id":1,"configName":"test1","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":2,"configName":"test2","desc":"Ram2","configparam":[{"removeit":"[]"}]},
{"id":3,"configName":"test3","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]}]    

output:
[{"id":1,"configName":"test1","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[]},
{"id":2,"configName":"test2","desc":"Ram2","configparam":[]},
{"id":3,"configName":"test3","desc":"Ram1","configparam":[{"paramId":"4","paramvalue":"200"}]}]

Comment: That does not look like `df.schema`. Schema should have data types mentioned.